# adjust graphic tick marks when sliderInput range changes

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

Consider this small toy shiny app. I have 21 years of data and originally I set
the X axis ticks at every year, however, the graphic gets too crowded after 10 years.
I would like to set the tick marks at every 5 years when the slider range is 10 years or more.
How can I make the graph react and show tick marks every 5 years instead of every year
when I select a range of more than 10 years on the sliderInput?

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)
library(shinythemes)
library(plotly)
library(scales)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinydashboard)
library(DT)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinycssloaders)

# Define input choices
type <- c("lambda","indices")


#############Lambda######Table###21 Years

lambda <- structure(list(year = 1991:2010, lambda = c(0.73392, 0.75659, 
                                                      1.33665, 1.06641, 1.27145, 1.01077, 0.66983, 1.6427, 0.96414, 
                                                      0.55648, 0.50556, 1.08024, 0.8706, 0.89665, 1.00807, 1.01967, 
                                                      0.73131, 1.1161, 1.10219, 1.35085)), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = "data.frame")

############Indices###############

indices <- structure(list(year = c(1991L, 1991L, 1991L, 1991L, 1991L, 1992L, 
                        1992L, 1992L, 1992L, 1992L, 1993L, 1993L, 1993L, 1993L, 1993L, 
                        1994L, 1994L, 1994L, 1994L, 1994L, 1995L, 1995L, 1995L, 1995L, 
                        1995L, 1996L, 1996L, 1996L, 1996L, 1996L, 1997L, 1997L, 1997L, 
                        1997L, 1997L, 1998L, 1998L, 1998L, 1998L, 1998L, 1999L, 1999L, 
                        1999L, 1999L, 1999L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2001L, 
                        2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2002L, 2002L, 2002L, 2002L, 2002L, 
                        2003L, 2003L, 2003L, 2003L, 2003L, 2004L, 2004L, 2004L, 2004L, 
                        2004L, 2005L, 2005L, 2005L, 2005L, 2005L, 2006L, 2006L, 2006L, 
                        2006L, 2006L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2008L, 2008L, 
                        2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2010L, 
                        2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L
), survey = c("fmwt", "kodiak", "twenty_mm", "stn", "fmwt_next_fall", 
              "fmwt", "kodiak", "twenty_mm", "stn", "fmwt_next_fall", "fmwt", 
              "kodiak", "twenty_mm", "stn", "fmwt_next_fall", "fmwt", "kodiak", 
              "twenty_mm", "stn", "fmwt_next_fall", "fmwt", "kodiak", "twenty_mm", 
              "stn", "fmwt_next_fall", "fmwt", "kodiak", "twenty_mm", "stn", 
              "fmwt_next_fall", "fmwt", "kodiak", "twenty_mm", "stn", "fmwt_next_fall", 
              "fmwt", "kodiak", "twenty_mm", "stn", "fmwt_next_fall", "fmwt", 
              "kodiak", "twenty_mm", "stn", "fmwt_next_fall", "fmwt", "kodiak", 
              "twenty_mm", "stn", "fmwt_next_fall", "fmwt", "kodiak", "twenty_mm", 
              "stn", "fmwt_next_fall", "fmwt", "kodiak", "twenty_mm", "stn", 
              "fmwt_next_fall", "fmwt", "kodiak", "twenty_mm", "stn", "fmwt_next_fall", 
              "fmwt", "kodiak", "twenty_mm", "stn", "fmwt_next_fall", "fmwt", 
              "kodiak", "twenty_mm", "stn", "fmwt_next_fall", "fmwt", "kodiak", 
              "twenty_mm", "stn", "fmwt_next_fall", "fmwt", "kodiak", "twenty_mm", 
              "stn", "fmwt_next_fall", "fmwt", "kodiak", "twenty_mm", "stn", 
              "fmwt_next_fall", "fmwt", "kodiak", "twenty_mm", "stn", "fmwt_next_fall", 
              "fmwt", "kodiak", "twenty_mm", "stn", "fmwt_next_fall", "fmwt", 
              "kodiak", "twenty_mm", "stn", "fmwt_next_fall"), count = c(4272700, 
                                                                         746630, 82277000, 15062000, 3261900, 3261900, 594290, 52437000, 
                                                                         10410000, 2375700, 2375700, 405550, 93451000, 15896000, 3369000, 
                                                                         3369000, 545450, 91811000, 16914000, 3576300, 3576300, 621220, 
                                                                         29044000, 23357000, 4578700, 4578700, 967300, 152080000, 23246000, 
                                                                         4530400, 4530400, 1292000, 101880000, 12817000, 2811200, 2811200, 
                                                                         792740, 106640000, 26432000, 5015100, 5015100, 1233700, 117860000, 
                                                                         24866000, 4789200, 4789200, 817530, 69885000, 11261000, 2507600, 
                                                                         2507600, 427530, 26717000, 5450000, 1294800, 1294800, 240160, 
                                                                         32388000, 6512400, 1527600, 1527600, 266360, 26950000, 5530300, 
                                                                         1307300, 1307300, 245170, 25831000, 4880000, 1163700, 1163700, 
                                                                         204690, 27068000, 5216900, 1205600, 1205600, 221410, 28206000, 
                                                                         5057900, 1200900, 1200900, 204580, 17965000, 3595500, 870900, 
                                                                         870900, 150400, 21173000, 4182700, 1008500, 1008500, 180080, 
                                                                         25575000, 4678100, 1121300, 1121300, 196020, 30689000, 6585500, 
                                                                         1541100, 1541100, 285520, 24986000, 11434000, 0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                -105L))

# Define UI 
ui <- fluidPage(sidebarPanel(h3("Select Model Output"),
                                   
                selectInput(inputId = "graphtype",
                 label = "Graphic",
                choices = type,
                selected = "lambda"),
            
                sliderInput(inputId =  "Yearslider",
                label = "Years to plot",
                sep = "",
              min = min(lambda$year),  
              max = max(lambda$year),
              step = 1,
              value = c(min = min(lambda$year)+8,max = max(lambda$year)-7))),
              mainPanel(plotOutput(outputId = "plot"))
                                         )


###################################################################################################################
server<- function (input, output, session) {
  session$onSessionEnded(function() {
    stopApp()
  })
  
  plot_data_lambda21 <- reactive({
    lambda[lambda$year >= input$Yearslider[1] & lambda$year <= input$Yearslider[2], ] 
  }) 
  
  plot_data_indices21 <- reactive({
    indices[indices$year >= input$Yearslider[1] & indices$year <= input$Yearslider[2], ] 
  })
  
  
  
  dataInput <- reactive({
    switch(input$graphtype,
           "lambda" = plot_data_lambda21(),
           "indices" = plot_data_indices21())
    
  })
  
  # Plot data
  create_plots <- reactive({
    
    #Make the plots
    theme_set(theme_classic(14)) 
    xlabels <- c(min(lambda$year):max(lambda$year))
    if (input$graphtype == "lambda") {
      ggplot(plot_data_lambda21(),aes(year,lambda)) + geom_line(size=1.5,colour="blue") + 
        geom_point(colour="orange",size=4) + geom_hline(yintercept=1,color="hotpink",linetype="dashed") +
       scale_x_continuous("",labels=xlabels,breaks=xlabels) + 
        theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 0.5)) 
        
    }
    
    else if(input$graphtype == "indices") {
      disable("Fixed")
      theme_set(theme_classic(14)) 
      xlabels <- c(min(lambda$year):max(lambda$year))
      ggplot(plot_data_indices21(),aes(year,count/1000,color=survey)) + 
        geom_line(size=1) + geom_point(shape=21, fill="lightgoldenrod", color="darkred",size=2) +
        scale_x_continuous("",labels=xlabels,breaks=xlabels) + 
        scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma) + 
        theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 60,vjust=0.5)) 
    }
    
  })
  
  #Refresh the slider
  updateSlider <-  reactive({
    if (input$graphtype == "lambda") {
      min = min(lambda$year)
      max = max(lambda$year)
    }
  else if(input$graphtype == "indices") {
      min = min(lambda$year)
      max=max(lambda$year)
    }
    updateSliderInput(session, "Yearslider", min=min, max=max) 
  })   
  
  #Render plots
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    updateSlider()
    create_plots()     
  })
  
}
# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server) # ,options = list(height = 1080)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an `if` condition to set the breaks depending on the range of the the years selected via the `sliderInput`:

```
# Plot data
  create_plots <- reactive({
    # Make the plots
    theme_set(theme_classic(14))
    if (diff(input$Yearslider) >= 10) {
      xlabels <- seq(input$Yearslider[1], input$Yearslider[2], by = 5)  
    } else {
      xlabels <- seq(input$Yearslider[1], input$Yearslider[2], by = 1)
    }
    
    if (input$graphtype == "lambda") {
      ggplot(plot_data_lambda21(), aes(year, lambda)) +
        geom_line(size = 1.5, colour = "blue") +
        geom_point(colour = "orange", size = 4) +
        geom_hline(yintercept = 1, color = "hotpink", linetype = "dashed") +
        scale_x_continuous("", breaks = xlabels) +
        theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 0.5))
    } else if (input$graphtype == "indices") {
      disable("Fixed")
      theme_set(theme_classic(14))
      ggplot(plot_data_indices21(), aes(year, count / 1000, color = survey)) +
        geom_line(size = 1) +
        geom_point(shape = 21, fill = "lightgoldenrod", color = "darkred", size = 2) +
        scale_x_continuous("", breaks = xlabels) +
        scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma) +
        theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 60, vjust = 0.5))
    }
  })
```

[image]

Comment: Great!! it works as expected @Stefan